# Open new link from the same chrome tab (chromedriver) - Python

Tags: python, selenium, tabs, selenium-chromedriver

I open a second tab with the command indicated below. With which command do I open a new link using the same tab?

`driver.execute_script("window.open('www.example');")`

Comment: [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086773/selenium-webdriver-python-reload-html-without-refreshing-the-page)This link will help you to resolve this

Comment: mmm sorry, I don't understand. I would like to open a new link `(driver.execute_script ("window.open ('www.example2');") ` from the same tab previously opened with 
`(driver.execute_script("window.open('www.example');")`

Answer (score 0):

Open a new tab as here and then verify than the correct link is opened [How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver) or here [Open web in new tab Selenium + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")

body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')

driver.close()
```

For asserting use:

```
assert driver.title == "Expected page title"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the guide, but I would like to open a new link in the same current tab, as if in the current open tab I paste a new link from the address bar. I hope I was clear

Comment: If you want to open a link in the same tab, why don't you just use: driver.get("https://somesite.com")  ?

Comment: because I have to open it in the same tab. the command driver.get, at least to me, only refreshes the first tab still open. I need to do it in the second tab